# View stream history in perforce

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to view all changelists that were made in the context of a stream in perforce? I am interested in a command line way.

Similar question: suppose I have a stream and its parent. Is it possible to find the changelist that is their latest common ancestor?

Comment: `p4 changes //Stream/name/...` is a good place to start for the first question, and `p4 interchanges` is a good place to start for the second question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see not only locally made changes but also those that are included via `import`, the simplest way is to switch to that stream and run the query in the context of the current client:

```
p4 switch STREAMNAME
p4 changes //CLIENTNAME/...
```

Changes made locally will usually be in the depot path that matches the stream name (e.g. `//stream/STREAMNAME/...`), but if you use `import+` this is not necessarily so (although if you use `import+` the concept of changes being made within the context of a particular stream goes out the window entirely).

---

Finding the changelist that is the "latest common ancestor" depends what you want to use this ancestor for and what you consider to be a "common ancestor" and even what "latest" means (the word "latest" implies most recent chronologically, but that's not necessarily the same as "closest" in terms of having the most commonality).  Some general approaches that might be useful:

1. Use the `p4 istat` command to see when the last merge/copy operations happened and what the latest change was that each included.
2. Use the `p4 changes -i` command on each stream to see what changelists it includes (including integrated ancestors), and diff to find the common ancestors.
3. Use the `p4 integrate -o` command to see the merge base for each file, and get the associated changelist with `p4 changes` or `p4 files`.

Comment: Regarding latest common ancestror, the usage scenario is the following: I have a child stream (suppose that I am implementing a feature) and I want to see the changes that have been made on that stream and have not been copied to the parent. 

By "latest common ancestor" I mean the latest changelist of the parent stream that has been merged down to the child. If I could find that changelist I could update to that snapshot and then compare it with the head of the child.

Comment: Wait -- the whole time your question was really "how do I build my own version of the `p4 interchanges` command?"  Why would you want to do that rather than just use the existing command?  :)

Comment: I am asking a question because I do not know what is the existing command. It is simple as that: there has been work on a feature on a child stream. I want to be able to see the work that has been done (i.e. a diff with latest common ancestor or any equivalent) and ideally the sequence of submits that brought about those changes.

Comment: `p4 interchanges` is the command you want.  It does what I suggested in part 3 of my answer to your second question, gives its output in the form you were asking for in your first question, and also implements the logic in between that you were going to need to write in a script.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sam Stafford for pointing this out.

First use

```
p4 interchanges -S <child_stream_name>
```

This will give you a list of the changes that have not been copied up the parent branch.

To view diffs you can either use "p4 describe" on each of the changelists in the list.